# Use current logged on user's information in query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, authentication

I have a form (using formmaker plugin) that I record information to display to the user at a later time.

I'd like to be able to record/insert the current logged in user's id (call it user_login) so I can have something like `WHERE wpuser_login = user_login` as part of a query.

I was thinking that I could join the wp_users table and query using a 'view' but I'm not sure how I could do that. In the meantime I think I'm just oging to add a field for the user to input their user id themselves then join wp_users using the above WHERE clause. The only problem with that is that the user would have to have the correct username, otherwise display will not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: What programming language are you using for your application in general? What you might be able to do, is store the user's id as a class level variable when they log in, and clear it when they log out or something. Then, you can just use some sort of injection to add that users id into the query.

Comment: that is obviously php wordpress

Comment: @Alex it's not obvious to someone who's never used either. Does my idea still hold? Can you store variables in php, or at least fetch the user's id at the time of querying and inject it somehow?

Comment: :-) I just answered your question.

Comment: Yes it is wordpress.  Problem is that the plugin doesn't seem to allow php code within it's queries.  The solution I had of making a username field won't work either since I would need to find the logged in users information with maybe a get_current_user() function.  I was also just experimenting with INSERT SELECT statement with no luck because of the same problem of finding the current logged in user.

Comment: I figured it out I think by including this php code into my wordpress page just before and just after the form insertion.  Problem is I can't get MAX(ID) or LAST_INSERT_ID() to work for me...executing query {'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM table1'} in phpmyadmin gives all zero values..and using 'LAST_INSERT_ID(id) gives all id values.    Any ideas on this one.   I've inserted the variable I need into the table using, for example, {'id = '10''}

Comment: Oddly enough querying: SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1   works fine..

Comment: Just an update -- I'm still working on it, closest I've gotten is: $wpdb->get_results("UPDATE `Windows_submissions` SET `username`='test3' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)")

Comment: I think I got it!  Using:                                                                                $wpdb->get_results("UPDATE `Windows_submissions` SET `username` = '$current_user->user_login' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");